Changing default port number in conf file is still allowing me to login to mysql via 3306
I thought that by changing the port of mysql conf file, 3306 would be disabled automatically.
cat /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf :
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
# pid-file      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
# socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 7029
# datadir       = /var/lib/mysql

But I am able to login at 3306 using mysql --user=root --port=3306 -p - shouldn't this be disabled ?
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep ':3306'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33060           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2528563/mysqld


Have you restarted the instance ?

Yes, the sys admin did this and it reflected when I tried logging in using the custom port. The default port is also working though.

There can be more than one config file, and there are other ways to set mysqld options. Also, 3306 <> 33060

as @mustaccio said there can be multiple cnf files see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location
